# docker compose / spring boot | Error : Unable to access jarfile app.jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my spring boot application (with MariaDB and Redis) using docker compose.

I used `docker compose up -d` command and checked that all my containers were running.

But the spring boot container showed me some logs, `Error : Unable to access jarfile app.jar`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./build/libs/plantodo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  maria:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - plantodo-mariadb-data:/var/lib/mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pepper27913@
      MARIADB_DATABASE: plantodo
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/data
      - ./redis/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/conf/redis.conf
    labels:
      - 'name=redis'
      - 'mode=standalone'
    command: redis-server /usr/local/conf/redis.conf
  app:
    build: .
    command: java -jar app.jar
    image: eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      MARIADB_HOST: mariadb
      MARIADB_USER: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: pepper27913@
      MARIADB_DB: plantodo

volumes:
  plantodo-mariadb-data:
```

I tried to build the spring boot container without using `docker compose up -d` command.

It builds successfully. I don't know what causes the problem.

```
[+] Building 4.4s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 382B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine                                   0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.6s
 => => transferring context: 51.46MB                                                                               0.6s
 => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                      0.0s
 => [3/3] COPY ./build/libs/plantodo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar                                                    3.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                             0.4s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.4s
 => => writing image sha256:2c8d67361f3dac4117b18de5ed28f5c188874bd94cdfeeb37789b578b9c666b0                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/plantodo/app                                                                            0.0s
```